# Can a question with an accepted answer be updated with results of suggestions?

Tags: discussion

I asked [How do I progress with this death record?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/1602/how-do-i-identify-the-location-and-cause-of-death-of-a-person-who-died-in-1992) and accepted an answer. Since then I have undertaken the great suggestions and while not fully resolved, I have progressed somewhat. Am I able to use the question to report back my results or would this be extra 'chatter'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolutely!

I've done that quite often over at Stack Overflow. When I finally solve my problem, or find a better solution, I go back and add a followup to my question.

See, for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419945/how-do-i-choose-between-the-various-ways-to-do-threading-in-delphi), where I later added an "edit" and then finally a "conclusion".

It is what makes a question complete. You get the question, a number of answers, an accepted answer, and the final reasoning/thoughts of the person who originally asked the question.

It should not be used to restart the conversation, but just to complete it.

Comment: +1 because I could not agree more.  What I like to see are clear Questions with clear Answers - the first draft of either is rarely going to be the best possible.

Comment: I'd also add if you do have new questions based on your results, ask them in a new question, not as an "update" on the old question.